# Abort ajax request in datatable

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

I want to abort previous all ajax request when current ajax request processing in datatable. I try some code to abort request but it can't working.

How can i abort in datatable?

```
        $('#ABC').DataTable({
        "destroy": true,
        language: {
            processing: "<img src='" + $('#ajaxImageUrl').val() + "'/>"
        },
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": 0,
            "orderable": false
        }],
        "ajax": {
            url: 'url',
            type: "post",
            beforeSend:function(jqXHR, settings){
                if(settings.nTable.jqXHR)
                    settings.nTable.jqXHR.abort();
            },
            xhr: function() {
                var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    //code
                }
                xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
                    setDesign();
                     xhrCount++;
                };
                return xhr;
            },
        }
    });
```

Comment: if you store the ajax request in a variable you can use .abort(); I believe.

Comment: it display always null